# Search for filename using variable in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that is supposed to search for a filename within a folder on a server and if that file exists the user is prompted to either overwrite the file or not. However, the code always prompts the user regardless of the file existing or not.

I found a few examples off of this site, however they use static file names. I am attempting to modify it to fit my needs, but not getting anywhere.

The code for finding if the file exists is as follows

```
'checks if file you're saving already exists
    If FileThere("\\showdog\service\Service_job_PO\" & UserInput) = True Then
        'do stuff here
```

the function for that code is this:

```
Function FileThere(filename As String) As Boolean
 If FileThere = (Dir("\\showdog\service\Service_job_PO\" & UserInput) <> "") Then
 FileThere = True
 Else
 FileThere = False
 End If     
End Function
```

Comment: what are you using as the user input?

Comment: UserInput is what the user is saving the file as. It is supposed to be checking to see if the name the user declares already exists within that directory.

Comment: Yes I know, but using wildcards or formatting that incorrectly can obviously cause issues. What have you tried that didn't work correctly?

Comment: Well, when it is run it always tells me that file exists regardless of it actually existing. I've attempted formatting it in different ways, such as double quotes instead of single, and by changing `<> ""`  to `>""`  and so on with no luck. So i'm guessing there is an alternate way to format this to make it work as intended...yet I have no luck

Comment: I have very similar code that works as intended. Please try adding MsgBox(Dir("\\showdog\service\Service_job_PO\" & UserInput)) to your FileThere function to find out what it is returning and post the results. Hopefully this gives you some insight into what is happening. For example, if I leave my input blank, it returns the first file in the directory. My guess is that you need to add a check to ensure that the UserInput is not blank.

Comment: After looking at the original code you posted again, I believe kyle has it right. You're passing it the path twice ... and you're using UserInput instead of filename. Only put the full path in one place ... if you have it in both, of course you're going to get errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should be the below. You want to check if the directory associated with the passed parameter `filename` exists.

```
Function FileThere(filename As String) As Boolean
 If Dir(filename) <> "" Then
 FileThere = True
 Else
 FileThere = False
 End If     
End Function
```

Edit:

I'm assuming you feed the full file path in this line, in which case you reference the file path that is sent over to the function `FileThere`.

```
 If FileThere("\\showdog\service\Service_job_PO\" & UserInput) = True Then
```

Comment: But how would I get to the directory where that file is present? Without including the file path wouldn't that defeat the purpose? Or am I over thinking it?

Answer (score 0):

You can cut this all down to a single test rather than double-up with a UDF:

```
If Len(Dir("\\showdog\service\Service_job_PO\" & UserInput)) > 0 Then
```

As per other comments above your initial code was using *UserInput* twice